# Improving SEO on images when the company name has generic word?

Tags: seo

So we have a really generic word like beach but the company is call beach stockholm, so what will the best possible way to make this when we have search like `beach ad campaign`

EDIT:

What I have in mind to try:

**-** Add proper meta tags to all images and meaning full names for example:

```
<img src="/path/to/image/2015-ad-campaing-red-flag.png" alt="2015 Red Flag Beach Campaign">
```

**-** Reduce and optimize images for better speed, since this affects SEO.

**-** Use google image site map [Sample](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en)

But is there something else I could so can give the best service possible when it comes to clients that had such a generic name?

cheers

Comment: This can be a rather broad topic even though you have narrowed it down a bit. Helps us help you. What have you tried or have in mind to try??

Comment: @closetnoc I updated

Comment: Your under the 1990's assumption that a related image has to have revelant keywords in order to rank the page. Google can estiblish what the page is about just fine with just text. Images, Headers, Metas and so forth are purely indicators, not DO THIS or you won't rank. Most SEO is off page, not on.

Comment: what do you mean is off page? @bybe

Comment: off page = off site.

Comment: im lost, there... I know what it means but I dont understand how is done off page/site?

Comment: I disagree massively with bybe, if you have really bad on site seo it can really hamper your seo. Optimising your images like this is great advice, improves your on page seo and improves the chances of being found in image search.

Comment: @Max I can't find anything to support the other argument, just yours... So im going with your point of view which is the same as mine

Answer (score 1):

Since you are concerned about company name, I will start there and then move on to images.

You will need to signal to Google your company name. You can do this best by using schema.org mark-up for local business https://schema.org/LocalBusiness, corporation https://schema.org/Corporation, NGO https://schema.org/NGO or any of the other options found toward the bottom of https://schema.org/Organization. You will want to place this on your Contact, About, or any other similar page or in the footer or header of your site. You want to make sure this is easily found and one of the ways this is done is either putting the information in each page or in a traditional page such as the ones I already listed.

This will create the semantic links to know about your company and how terms used on your site relate to your company. In this case, it will recognize that the term beach can refer to your company name in some cases. For this, I would suggest being less ambiguous when you are referring to your company, though you do not have to be too verbose either. Just enough to distinguish the company from an actual beach.

As for images, the first thing you want to utilize is the image link. Here you can take advantage of the URI (path following the URL - example.com, URI /path/to/webpage/webpage.html). It helps to use a directory and file name that helps identify what the image is about. As well, you can use the alt text in the link to help specify what the image is about. In this case, you may want to use your company name for anything like your example so that your intent is clear.

As well, any header tag and content surrounding the image helps to identify what the image is about. You will want to surround your ad campaign images with semi-verbose content that describes your campaign at least once in a prominent place. From there, anytime the image is used, Google will understand the context of the image. This helps fill out the semantic links map that will help with image search.